# Jquery UI tabs: проблемы с отображением на мобильных устройствах

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Доброго времени суток. Заметил [проблему](http://nosorog.net/): при использовании Jquery UI tabs на мобильных устройствах (Ipad, Andriod) содержимое вкладок не отображается, как будто там ничего и нет. Причем на долю секунды содержимое все же появляется, а потом пропадает. Хотя, быть может, проблема в JavaScripte?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, лучше было бы для мобильников сделать отдельную версию и использовать [мобильную версию библиотеки](http://jquerymobile.com), попробуйте. Может получиться.